# Using UIButton as a Switch

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I am trying to use a UIButton as a switch. When the button is tapped, the button image should change to (atcs.png) and state should be (.selected). 
When image is tapped again, the button image should again to (actns.png) and state should be (.normal).

Below is an example of my current code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var atcBtn: UIButton!

@IBAction func atcTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if atcBtn.isSelected {
        atcBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "atcs.png"), for:.selected)
    } else {
        atcBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "atcns.png"), for:.normal)
    }
}
```

This somehow isn't working. Is there anything missing? Tried almost every solution listed on here, but nothing.

Comment: You should only set the two images once, in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: _Swift coding tips_ - 1) it's usual in Swift for variable names to be less "concise"… appending `Button` rather than `Btn` is more normal. 2) Actions are better named as what is actually happening, so `toggleAtcState` rather than `atcTapped`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, move your `setImage` code to `viewDidLoad`. There's no reason to repeatedly set these images:

```
atcBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "atcs.png"), for:.selected)
atcBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "atcns.png"), for:.normal)
```

Next, toggle the `isSelected` property when the button is tapped:

```
@IBAction func atcTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
}
```

Also of note - use `sender` instead of hardcoding `atcBtn`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am getting an error with the line of code below:
    
sender.isSelected ? sender.isSelected = false : sender.isSelected = true

it's saying: Result values in '? :' expression have mismatching types '()' and 'Bool'

Comment: It should simply be `sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected` (assuming you want to toggle the state).

Comment: Good point. I struggled with the best syntax and always forget of this. I'll edit.